# Open Network for OctoPi

Tags: raspberry-pi-imager

My college requested that I attempt to solve a list of 3D printing problems we have at the school. I decided that OctoPi was most likely the best option. Therefore, I have gone through all the simple installation steps, but have been stumped by connecting to our network. I found an old solution.....
[Connect to unsecured wireless network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15393/connect-to-unsecured-wireless-network)
...but this seems to be quite outdated and no longer able to solve the open network issue. What I have found is that you can access a couple of interesting lines of code in the octopi-wpa-supplicant file. In the file, you can find a couple of lines detailing Open/unsecured networks that seem to have the ability to be edited with a couple of different software.
[image]

My question is....
What if I were to edit the ssid="put SSID here" to my network's name and leave the key_mgmt=NONE for an open network, would that allow my Raspberry PI to openly connect to the LAN? Would this work? Has anyone tried? Thanks for any information that you may have.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Please, post as a text not screenshot

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `Has anyone tried?` ... what is preventing you from trying it yourself?

Comment: @jsotola I have not tried it. This is for a public school and therefore public network, so I do not have administrator access to find the IP in any way. When I go to my local octopi server it cannot detect the Pi, which is why I am looking for the IP Address. I have reached out to administration to solve this issue, I will update you then.